# Customising the text in Winforms title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winform based application. I just want to put some hyperlink on left side of the title bar as shown in the image below and add hyperlink to that. Is it possible in winforms?
In addition to that winform title bar will have a header as shown "Happy Days Design Suite"

Alternative solution would be remove the title bar completely and add labels, but before that I just want to check whether adding texts to the title bar would be possible

[image]

Comment: It depends how badly you want it, to get it right and perfect maybe a little tricky as there is no out-of-the-box way to do this, and will require a a degree of hackery

Comment: Yeah probably have to put in a message handler and handle the equivalent to `WM_NCPAINT`

Comment: One easier way, is to hide the `TitleBar` (no ControlBox, no MinimizeBox, no MaximizeBox, no Text) and build your own `TitleBar`, with a Panel and some Buttons and LinkLabels. You could use the `SystemInformations` properties to set the various parts in the *normal* size and colors. Handling the System Theme is more complicated. Flat Buttons help.

Comment: Another option is to do this with WPF and [MahApps](https://mahapps.com/) MetroWindow.

Comment: @Jimi I am following your way currently, but I just wanted to check if any other options

Comment: I wouldn't do that because desktop apps normally don't have links in the title, looks like a web page. Design it the way other desktop apps look since users are familiar with it.

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure I'd say that's _"easier"_.   There is replicating window drag; System Menu; to think about

Comment: @MickyD  Well, that's the easiest part. You could make a custom control of a Panel. Overriding `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseMove` you don't even need to PInvoke `SendMessage` and `ReleaseCapture()`. A System menu is more complicated. Can be faked, anyway, if it's really required (yep, I know, Keyboard-only Window movements gets hard). Otherwise, you'll have to override `WndPrc` or go to `DWM` rendering.

Comment: My experience with these sort of things is that yeah its all possible, but if you don't get it exactly right and perfect in all situations, it just makes the app look B-Grade. you are better to spend your time in other places.

Comment: @TheGeneral  That's the Truth. Probably, a little stripe under the TitleBar to show some links is good enough.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, it is true, that normally **WinForms** desktop apps don't have a link in their title bar. But a lot of modern **UWP** desktop applications with rich UI do have links, buttons and even textboxes in their title bar.

Comment: Agree @vasily.sib.  It's also more of a case of contemporary apps or specialised imaging or video production apps have extra adorners vs a specific technology choice.  Look at anything from Adobe.  Though not hyperlinks exactly, one has only to look at VS2017 or Office 365

Comment: Btw, if you decide to go on with this, **make a Template of a Form prototype**, do not modify each *regular* Form you add to the project, over and over. Build *the good one*, save as template and use the Visual Studio `Add -> Windows Form` to reload your template (I wrote template many times).

Comment: [Fancy Windows Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33716/Fancy-Windows-Forms)

Answer (score 3):

Not the answer the OP was looking for, but most likely the way that Microsoft *intended* - If you have space on the form, in the designer add a StatusStrip, then add a ToolStripStatusLabel to it.  ToolStripStatusLabel supports hyperlinks out of the box.

Life is short, take the path of least resistance.  WinForms is an opinionated framework and your safest bet is to do things their way.